# Is this a new method of finding a square of any number?

Tags: arithmetic, square-numbers

e.g. number $5$.

$5^2=25;$
If I add up the first $4$ **even** numbers and a half of the $5$th even number, we get $25$. 
$2+4+6+8+5=25$

So generally speaking, the sum of first $n-1$ even numbers and the half of $n$th number is equal to $n^2$.

I am interested if this is used somewhere? If not, could it be used?
Thanks!

Comment: This is because the mean of the first $n-1$ even numbers equals $n$. So, 2+4+6+8+5=5+5+5+5+5. Interesting trick, but I don't think it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first $n-1$ positive integers is $n(n-1)/2$ by a well known formula. Your sum is this multiplied by $2$, plus $n$, which is $n^2-n+n=n^2$. This is a relatively trivial observation.